# Problems with inserting a bit of PHP code into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a content management system, and I am currently using **BB** code to have the ability for special characters. The way this is set up is using 2 arrays, one to find the BB code and one with the stuff it needs to be replaced with.

Now the problem I am having is, that I need to have it execute a bit of PHP code when asked for. How would I go about doing that? Which makes my question: How do I insert the some PHP code into an array?

My code:

```
$replace = array(
  "@\n@",
  "/\[b\](.+?)\[\/b\]/is",
  "/\[code\=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/code\]/is"
);
$find = array(
   "<br />",
   "<strong>$1</strong>",
   "<?php include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/source/geshi/geshi.php'); $source=file_get_contents('file.php'); $language='$1'; $geshi=new GeSHi($source, $language); echo'<code class=\"num\">', implode(range(1,count(file('file.php'))), '<br />'), '</code>'; echo $geshi->parse_code(); ?>"
);
```

The error that I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or           T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /testing/bbcode.php on line 26
```

Thanks ahead

EDIT: Swapping single for double quotes and vice versa did the trick!

Now I have another problem:

When I have this:

```
"/\[color\=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/color\]/is",
```

In my $find array, and this in my $replace array:

```
"<font color=\"$1\">$2</font>",
```

It works fine, and renders the text as the color entered. Now with the [code=php][/code] for example, it does not render at all and just shows as "[code=php][/code]" as if nothing was rendered. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You need it to execute php code entered by the user? Are you insane?

Comment: If so, there are exactly ZERO ways to make this secure and about a billion ways to get around any protection you can think of. Everything from using variables for functions to concatenating variables to make function names, to using numbers for variable names...etc. You would never be able to secure this. And anything your php scripts can do (which is pretty much any command on your server) your users will be able to do to your server.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn , No, secured by a solid account system that is only accessable by me, and Im making it to learn, it wont be on a website anywhere :)

Comment: @JelleKerkstra , Line 25 is "<strong>$1</strong>"

Comment: Well your problem probably stems from the php code you have inside double quotes. Any of the variables will be translated to the variable value unless you escape the dollar signs on the variables.

Comment: So if I were to put a \ before every $-sign it would work?

Comment: I do not know, but that is one issue. You could also inverse all your quotes. trade single for double and vice versa. Single quotes do not parse variables.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick (swapping single for double quotes and vice versa, now I am having another problem, I'll edit the original post right now!

Comment: Using `''` (Single quotes) in PHP strings will display strictly. Using `""` (double quotes), will replace PHP variables with their values.

Comment: Second problem is with your pattern. Between the "code" tags, you have `(.+?)`. That means it would "match 1 or more of any character". If you have zero characters, it doesn't match so the pattern fails and doesn't get replaced. If you changed the `+` to a `*` then it would mean zero or more.

Comment: Ah okay, so basically now it executes what it's supposed to execute, but the result is not exactly what it should be: ", implode(range(1,count(file("secure.php"))), "
"), ""; echo $geshi->parse_code(); ?> 
I tried escaping several things but that did nothing, where is the problem now :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this will help you, but I'll post it on the off-chance you can adapt your code to the solution.  I built myself a page that accepts input from a `textarea`, and upon clicking a button the page will "execute" the PHP code within and display it's output in a `div` below the `textarea`.  Because it's in a browser, it can even do the same for JavaScript (and HTML/CSS), which makes it handy to do quick tests.

It looks like this:

[image]

It works by taking the PHP code from the `textarea`, and writing it out to a temporary file.  After the file is written, it is then included in an offscreen buffer via the `include` statement.  I then capture the buffer into a variable, and spit it out on the page.

This is what all of that looks like in practice:

```
$code = isset($_POST['code']) ? $_POST['code'] : '';
 
$filename = tempnam('.', '__');
file_put_contents($filename, $code);
    
ob_start();

include $filename;
$output = ob_get_clean();
    
unlink($filename);
```

Since your PHP code is really just text, you can assign it to an array just like you would any other piece of data:

```
$array = array();
$array[] = $code;
```

If you want to run your PHP code from a variable in memory, instead of going to disk, you can use `eval()`, but it works a little differently than the `include` method in that the code has to "return" something.  I'm not a fan of this method, but the option is there.

```
$code = isset($_POST['code']) ? $_POST['code'] : '';
$result = eval($code);
```

References:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: Hey, this is quite usefull but does not exactly help me with my problem since my code does not execute, but it reads it, highlights it and echo's it back using span's with styles. Thanks though, this is certainly usefull!

Comment: @BananaMan Ah, I must have misinterpreted your question then.  I thought you were trying to include PHP code from a user-inputable source.  :)

Comment: What my endgoal with this is basically, is using GeSHi (A syntax highlighter system), to be able to do something like [code=php]<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>[/code] in a textarea, and render it, and then echo it back with the correct syntaxing (which is what GeSHi does). Now the problem I'm having is with the BB code :(